# Symfony 2 Expression Validator Class Not Found

Tags: validation, symfony, expression, silex

I am trying to use the Symfony 2 expression validator in an experimental Silex application that I'm building. However, when I submit my form and the validation attempts to run, the following error is thrown:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'validator.expression' not found in /path/to/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Provider/Validator/ConstraintValidatorFactory.php on line 86
```

I am using the following package versions:

Silex - 2.0.*@dev

Symfony Form - 2.6.4

Symfony Validator - 2.6.4

In my Silex application bootstrap file I have initialized the validator service provider using the following line of code:

```
// validator
$app->register(new \Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider());
```

I have defined my validation rules using yaml:

```
street_address:
            - Expression:
                expression: "this.getStreetAddress() != '' || this.getCrossStreetAddress() != ''"
                message: "You must at least specify a street address (Line 1) or a cross street address"
                groups: [submit]
```

Does anyone have any idea about what I could be missing? Is there an additional package that I need to install? Is the expression validator not supported in Silex?

Comment: Are you sure to be able to use Yaml configuration with Silex?

Comment: Yes it is possible to use Yaml configuration with Silex. I am using Yaml configuration for many things including my validation but it was just the Expression validation which did not work.